# Detect multiple matches over time interval of validity, in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, duplicates, intervals

I have a table that matches ID1 to ID2, with two date columns that identify the time interval over which the match is valid. 
There can be multiple ID2 for each ID1, *but not over the same time interval*. Because of errors in the data imputation, however, these cases do exist in the table. I have to identify them.

Example: the last two records in this table have this issue: between 2005 and 2015, the ID1 44 is matched to two different ID2's numbers, 22 and 55.

```
ID1     ID2     startdate      enddate
 11      22     2000-01-01  2010-01-01  
 11      33     2010-01-01  9999-01-01  
 44      22     2000-01-01  2010-01-01  
 44      22     2010-01-01  9999-01-01  
 44      55     2005-01-01  2015-01-01
```

It would be enough to have just the list of distinct ID1 that have this issue, for starters; it would be even better if I could also identify all the records that conflict with the constraint.

Suggestions on the most elegant way to do this in Oracle SQL?

Comment: Doesn't the same problem apply to id2 too? Aren't there rows that contain id2 in the wrong interval or you need to check only id1?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id1 = t.id1 and t2.id2 <> t.id2 and
                    t2.startdate < t.enddate and
                    t2.enddate > t.startdate
             )
order by t.id1, t.startdate;
```

Comment: It does not seem to work (the query returned practically almost all the rows): this matches also single rows with no issues; maybe changing the conditions on the dates this can be solved

Comment: @Giuseppe . . . it also needs the condition on `id2`.

Answer (score 1):

With exists:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where (id1 = t.id1 and id2 <> t.id2) 
    and (
      startdate between t.startdate and t.enddate 
      or
      enddate between t.startdate and t.enddate
      or
      t.startdate between startdate and enddate 
      or
      t.enddate between startdate and enddate
    )   
)
```

Comment: Might be fine, but the conditions on the dates are too complicated and really increase the query running time a lot.

Comment: If I remove any of the conditions on the dates it does not return both rows of overlapping intervals, but only one. You can experiment with the conditions.

Comment: I see; let me check.